# Avoid a column in panel - extjs

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, extjs

I have created a panel and have 2 columns. Both the columns have many rows. On left side column there is a label in each row and on the right side column there are text fields in each row. In one of the rows I need a blank left column record and checkbox on the right side.
But when I leave a blank `items` value

```
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
layout: {
    type: 'table',
        columns: 2
},
    items: [
    { xxxxx},
    { xxxxx},
    {},
    {xxxxx}
    ]
}
```

In place of this empty {}, I am getting a thin blue line, whereas I need a blank row.

How do I obtain this (remove the thin blue line)?

Using firefox I found the id of the `div` element and wrote `display:none` but that works only for firefox not for IE.
I need a solution which is browser compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an empty string, and set the border to false, then that should get rid of that blue line :

```
{
   border:false,
   html: ' ',
}
```

Here is an example in jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/xj363e7f/1/